# I'm trying to find the amount of federal funding allocated to US cities since 1970. Blocks grants and earmarked funding

Tags: data.gov

I'm looking at changes in federal spending on cities since 1970, in ten-year intervals. Ideally, this data would be in two parts: 1) payments to cities that they could spend as they wish and 2) total federal support for cities including grants for specific purposes. I'm looking both for total dollar amounts and as a percentage of city spending.

I'm also looking for comparable figures of cities by US state.

My belief is that federal and state support for cities has declined, but I need to demonstrate or refute that claim. Any advice for a step in the right direction is helpful.

Comment: https://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/budget/Historicals